# insert is not a function in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i write this simple code to insert something in databse. my database is mongodb and I want to insert an object( a document ) in a collection in nodejs. something like this :

```
await InboxMessage.insert({
userId,
title,
body,
viewed: false,
deeplink: customData && customData.deeplink ? customData.deeplink : null,
```

})

but i get an error that says to me : ***error in reply to comment:  TypeError: InboxMessage.insert is not a function***

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using   [insertOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/#db.collection.insertOne) function :

> await db.collectionName.insertOne({});

```
await InboxMessage.insertOne({
 userId,
 title,
 body,
 viewed: false,
 deeplink: customData && customData.deeplink ? customData.deeplink : null,
});
```

if you are using mongoose npm then use [create](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) or [save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)

> await ModelName.create({});

```
await InboxMessage.create({
     userId,
     title,
     body,
     viewed: false,
     deeplink: customData && customData.deeplink ? customData.deeplink : null,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work with `insertOne()` function. Try using that...I was getting the same error which resolved by using `insertOne()` function and data was inserted in collection.